# Is there any method for making intermediate code of application platform independent?

Tags: .net, windows, linux

I just want to convert my .NET application to linux application is it possible that the MSIL is converted to any machine code like apple intel etc. or can be executed on any os independent of architechture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) is the way to run .NET code on other platforms other than Windows.

The Mono folks maintain a basic guide for cross-platform .NET development here: http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Portability

Comment: ok but mono is fully competable for linux etc. i don't think so can you tell me more about its competability?

Comment: Compatibility between .NET on Windows and on Linux (via Mono) is mostly in the area of what .NET frameworks are provided by Mono.  Here's a (slightly out-of-date) chart: http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility

Comment: So if your .NET application uses one of the unsupported frameworks, you'll need to find more cross-platform alternatives for those pieces.  *However*, Mono means you won't need to switch languages and you can even still develop and compile on Windows if you prefer.

Comment: When you chose .NET, you made a decision to be Windows specific. Now you only have a chance to try out cross platform CLR implementation such as Mono. And it is lucky that Mono grows so fast.

Answer (score 1):

[MSIL(CIL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) is already platform-independent.

You'll probably want to have a look at [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).